# Как понимать "явное / неявное преобразование" в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, терминология

Изучаю `javascript`. Постоянно сталкиваюсь со словом ***явное / неявное*** преобразование. Примерно понимаю, что это значит. Можете объяснить подробнее, как понимать это?

Например `call / apply` - это явное указание `this`. Что это значит?

Answer (score 3):

Явное преобразование - это когда разработчик сам намеренное преобразует один тип в другой. Например, `Number('5')` - строка '5' явно преобразуется в integer. (ещё типкастом называют)
Неявное - когда язык (в силу своей нестрогой типизации) сам преобразует значение в другой тип. Например, при нестрогом сравнении - `1 == '1'`.

В случае с `call/apply` мы указываем переменную, которая будет являться в контексте вызова `this` - то есть явно её задаём.

Answer (score 3):

Явное - это значит, что вы сами намеренно преобразуете значение:

```
(10).toString() // число > строка
parseInt('10') // строка > число
```

Неявно, это когда преобразование за вас делает движок в результате какого-то выражения

```
'10' + 10 // число 10 неявно превратиться в строку '10'
if(1) { } // 1 неявно превратится в значение true
```

В случае с `call`/`bind` мы явно задаем контекст, в котором будет вызвана функция

```
function fn() {
    console.log(this.prop); //
}

fn(); // unefined или ошибка в строгом режием
fn.call({prop: 1}); // 1, так как мы явно указали контекст {prop: 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пишу своими словами.

#### Явное преобразование

Под явным преобразованием подразумевается преобразование типа, которое вы сами инициируете в коде.

```
String(null) // преобразует значение null в строку со значением "null"
Number("123") // преобразует строку "123" в число 123
```

#### Неявное преобразование

Под неявным подразумевается преобразование типа, которое вы не указывали явно, но интерпретатор посчитал, что для выполнения операции нужен другой тип данных и изменил его самостоятельно.

```
var new = 'one' + 123 // Для выполнения конкатенации число 123 будет преобразовано в строку "123", хотя мы не давали таких инструкций явно

if (value) { } // Любое значение переменной `value` будеь приведено к булевому типу данных.
```

#### В заключение

Правила преобразований остаются одинаковыми всегда, вопрос только в том, кто инициирует изменение типа: вы или интерпретатор.

Answer (score 1):

Неявное преобразование происходит, когда интерпретатор преобразует тип без вашего участия. При явном преобразовании (приведении типов), вы сами каким-то образом должны указать желаемый тип данных.

```
console.log('15'+'14'); // неявное преобразование из строки в число
console.log(Number('15')+Number('14')); // явно указан тип Number
console.log(parseInt('15')); //намеренное преобразование строки в число с помощью parseInt()
```

[this](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods) используется для доступа к текущему объекту.

Метод [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) позволяет указать объект, на который будет ссылаться `this` во время вызова функции.

Метод [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) аналогичен методу `call()`, первый параметр также используется в качестве значения `this`, а остальные передаются в виде массива.

Comment: Супер объяснения, спасибо всем!